# Reading between start and end position in excel

Tags: java

Currently I am reading an entire excel file with below condition -

```
 while (rowIterator.hasNext() )
{
do operations ()
}
```

Now I am trying to read from particular block of rownumbers and if I provide the below code

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext() &&  rowIterator.next().getRowNum() > start && rowIterator.next().getRowNum() < end)
```

its not working ,what would be a workaround

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood how iterator works in Java. You can think there is a pointer inside each iterator. When you call `next()`, the pointer moves to the next position. Therefore, you make two 'next()' calls in your while condition, which makes the pointer move two steps away from your current position. This is incorrect.

Try this:

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    next = rowIterator.next();
    if (next > start && next < end) {
         // do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I changed it to "  for (int rowNum = start; rowNum < end; rowNum++) 
      
      {
       
       System.out.println("Entering the while loop ....");
          //Row row = rowIterator.next();
          Row row = mySheet.getRow(rowNum);" and it worked , do you think this is fine ?

Comment: Definitely, you just avoid the iterator.